What is a work of Russian literature, in which a gentleman gets lost in a rain with a coachman, who for a long time did not admit that he was lost?
This work dates back to the 19th century.
Perhaps it was not rain, but a snowstorm.
Excluded works with similar plots: “Dead Souls” by N.V. Gogol, “Blizzard” by A.S. Pushkin, “Blizzard” by L.N. Tolstoy, “Tosca” by A.P. Chekhov.

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. To make this work easier to identify, please add any information you have of the kind listed at the tag wiki for identification requests. This includes details about where and when you read it, what the publication date seemed to be, what the book looked like, etc. Please edit your question to add these details, don't provide them in the comments. Thanks!

do they both stay alive?

I believe it is The Captain's Daughter by A. Pushkin, chapter 2. Try that.

When you return, if someone has posted the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].


The snow drifted round and covered us. The horses went at a walk, and soon stopped altogether.
"Why don't you go on?" I said, impatiently, to the driver.
"But where to?" he replied, getting out of the sledge. "Heaven only knows where we are now. There is no longer any road, and it is all dark."
I began to scold him, but Savéliitch took his part.
"Why did you not listen to him?" he said to me, angrily. "You would have gone back to the post-house; you would have had some tea; you could have slept till morning; the storm would have blown over, and we should have started. And why such haste? Had it been to get married, now!"

This is Chapter 2 from A. Pushkin's The Daughter of the Commandant
Pyotr gives the peasant who saved him a hareskin coat as thanks, which becomes plot significant later in the book when he encounters the same man during the rebellion, and is saved from execution.
